# How to conditionally deserialize a json based on the property value

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a json incoming and I want to deserialize to the Class only if a property value is matching a specific string.
eg:
My json is :

```
[
{
"string1": "a";
"string2": "b";
"string3": "c";
isActive: true
},
{
"string1": "d";
"string2": "e";
"string3": "f";
isActive: false
}
]
```

My Class is:

```
public class InboundJson
{
    public string string1 { get; set; }
    public string string2 { get; set; }
    public string string3 { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
}

InboundJson jsonobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InboundJson>(result);
```

This works fine and converts the incoming json to object of InboundJson class.

As you can see I have a json array with two parts. I need to deserialize in to the class only if isActive == false.

Any idea how this is possible?(other than manipulating the incoming json string)

Comment: You cannot check isActive without deserializing. You wil have to do it in post-processing.

Comment: You could potentially deserialize a fragment (in this case your IsActive) and then decide to deserialize the whole thing. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any idea how this is possible?

> This is **not** possible.

As @PalleDue said, you can do it post deserialization using [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) clause

```
List<InboundJson> jsonobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InboundJson>>(result);

var result = jsonobj.Where(x => x.isActive);
```